# LDAP Authentication php doesn't work with certain characters

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm connecting with the following code to a MS AD-server via php:

```
<?php
    $login='domain\\username';
    $password='somepaswordwithç';
    $ldap=ldap_connect("someserver.com");
    if ($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $login, $password)) {
        echo "ok";
    }
    else{
        echo "error while connecting";
    }
?>
```

It works with other characters like + / - * " ' but not with ç and possibly some other special characters.

In my original code, I'm getting the values from a post, but the problem is the same when I just put the password in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It apears I forgot to set the ldap option:

```
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

So the correct code is:

```
<?php
    $login='domain\\username';
    $password='somepaswordwithç';
    $ldap=ldap_connect("someserver.com");
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    if ($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $login, $password)) {
        echo "ok";
    }
    else{
        echo "error while connecting";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue and it seems to resolve it. Any idea why we have to specify the version ?

Comment: Nope, but if it works, it works, I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯